# Discord.Py create private channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'd like to do private channels through my bot but I have a mistake. Here's my code:

```
@client.command(name='create', help="Créer un salon privé")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True, manage_roles=True)
async def create(ctx, *, nom_de_salon):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = nom_de_salon
    await guild.create_role(name=role)
    member : ctx.author
    autorize_role = get(guild.roles, name=role)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        autorize_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    await guild.create_text_channel(nom_de_salon, overwrites=overwrites)
    await client.add_role(member, role)
```

And here's the mistake :
`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few small mistakes in your code. But the reason for the error is in the last line. The role name has no ID, the role object is required here. [discord.Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.id)
I have corrected your code, so it works.

```
@client.command(name='create', help="Créer un salon privé")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True, manage_roles=True)
async def create(ctx, *, nom_de_salon):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = nom_de_salon
    autorize_role = await guild.create_role(name=role)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        autorize_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    await guild.create_text_channel(nom_de_salon, overwrites=overwrites)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(autorize_role)
```